# Querying DOM of a Backbone.js app with Zombie.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, zombie.js, vows

Just trying out [Zombie.js](http://zombie.labnotes.org/) for the first time today, and I'm having trouble visiting a page that populates DOM elements via javascript (specifically, a Backbone.js app).  As a quick example, I visited the [Backbone.js Todo app](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/examples/todos/index.html) and manually added a few items.  Then I tried to grab the html within the `#todo-list` element using Zombie, and it came back empty.  I've set `browser.runScripts = true`, so shouldn't everything be ready for Zombie to query?

Looking at the source, the inner HTML is indeed empty.  Is this even possible with Zombie.js?  Or do I need to use something like Jasmine, as done [here](http://tinnedfruit.com/2011/03/03/testing-backbone-apps-with-jasmine-sinon.html)?

I've included example code below, along with the response I get.

```
var zombie = require('zombie'),
vows = require('vows'),
assert = require('assert');

var baseUrl = 'http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/examples/todos/index.html';

vows.describe('Zombie Tests on a Backbone App').addBatch({
'Navigate to Todo List' : {
  topic: function () {
    browser = new zombie.Browser({ debug: true });
    browser.runScripts = true;
    browser.on('error',function (err){console.log(err.stack)});
    browser.visit(baseUrl, this.callback);
  },
  'Can see todo list' : function (err,browser,status) {
    console.log('todo-list inner:' + browser.querySelector("#todo-list").innerHTML);
    // actual tests would go here
  }
},
}).export(module);
```

And the output from running `vows`:

```
> vows test/todo-test.js --spec

♢ Zombie Tests on a Backbone App

Zombie: GET http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/examples/todos/index.html
Zombie: GET http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/examples/todos/index.html => 200
Zombie: GET http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/test/vendor/json2.js
Zombie: GET http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/test/vendor/jquery-1.5.js
Zombie: GET http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/test/vendor/underscore-1.1.6.js
Zombie: GET http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/backbone.js
Zombie: GET http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/examples/backbone-localstorage.js
Zombie: GET http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/examples/todos/todos.js
Zombie: GET http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/examples/backbone-localstorage.js => 200
Zombie: GET http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/test/vendor/json2.js => 200
Zombie: GET http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/test/vendor/underscore-1.1.6.js => 200
Zombie: GET http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/backbone.js => 200
Zombie: GET http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/examples/todos/todos.js => 200
Zombie: GET http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/test/vendor/jquery-1.5.js => 200
Zombie: Firing timeout 1, delay: 1
todolist inner:
  Navigate to Todo List
    ✓ Can see todo list

✓ OK » 1 honored (3.824s)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `browser.html` method, then your example works — I think the problem comes from the `browser` object not having a `querySelector` method (it does have a [`query` and `queryAll` method](http://zombie.labnotes.org/API.html#browser-html-selector-context-String), though).

Here's the revised, working snippet:

```
'Can see todo list' : function (err, browser, status) {
  var list = browser.html('#todo-list');
  console.log('todo-list inner: ' + list);
  // actual tests would go here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the visit method is calling back too early. Try waiting for the 'done' event, e.g. `browser.on('done', this.callback)`.